# How to remove all file when app is removed by user?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I have blackberry app (java). My app stores some informations in files (file:///store/home/user/app_name/). When user removes app, these files don't delete.
I want to delete files when app is removed by user.
What is solution?

Comment: There is no standard callback method that notifies the MIDlet that it is being removed. Maybe a Blackberry specific API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store files this way - use Persistable for your app data instead: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_objects_persistently_1219782_11.jsp

Comment: Yes it is good solutions. But I need keep information exectly in files.

Comment: Jonathan in cases when there's a lot of data/objects to be stored PersistentStore is not a suitable place. Filesystem on media card is far more better. It is because PersistentStore is a limited storage, and it consumes memory shared with operating system. And when there's insufficient memory for OS, then device works unstable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two "standard" ways to uninstall an application. The first, via `Options - Applications` menu. And the second, via `javaloader -erase -f` command.

Theoretically you can intercept the uninstall event for the first way (when you use "Options - Applications" menu), but you need additional application that receives this event and does the cleanup action.

To intercept and recognize an unknown event I do the following.

I write a simple BlackBerry app, that implements and uses GlobalEventListener and runs in background, and prints every intercepted **global event guid** to the system output and/or log with timestamps.

Now, uninstall your app from Options menu and inspect logged global event guids. After that install/uninstall another applications. And then inspect log/system output window to find out which events are related to `uninstall` action.

It does not guarantee 100% result, but at least you will get fun with coding, logging and exploring.